# comparing strings read from a file

Tags: c, string, file-handling

I wrote a program, in which a user enters a string, and that string is compared to every string in a file. If any string or sub-string in the file matches with string user entered, that strings in the file should be displayed.

Content of my NOW.txt file:

```
india

ind

in

indian

i

indians
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,n,p;
    char m[50], d[50];
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("NOW.TXT","r");
    printf("Enter a word\n");
    scanf("%s", m);
    n = strlen(m);

    while( fgets (d, 50, fp)!=NULL ) 
    {    
         p=strlen(d);

         for(j=0; j<p; j++){
        for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4] && m[5]== d[5] && m[6]== d[6] && m[7]==d[7] && m[8]==d[8] && m[9]==d[9] && m[10]==d[10] && m[11]==d[11] && m[12]==d[12] && m[13]==d[13] && m[14]==d[14] && m[15]==d[15])
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4] && m[5]== d[5] && m[6]== d[6] && m[7]==d[7] && m[8]==d[8] && m[9]==d[9] && m[10]==d[10] && m[11]==d[11] && m[12]==d[12] && m[13]==d[13] && m[14]==d[14] )
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4] && m[5]== d[5] && m[6]== d[6] && m[7]==d[7] && m[8]==d[8] && m[9]==d[9] && m[10]==d[10] && m[11]==d[11] && m[12]==d[12] && m[13]==d[13] )
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4] && m[5]== d[5] && m[6]== d[6] && m[7]==d[7] && m[8]==d[8] && m[9]==d[9] && m[10]==d[10] && m[11]==d[11] && m[12]==d[12])
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4] && m[5]== d[5] && m[6]== d[6] && m[7]==d[7] && m[8]==d[8] && m[9]==d[9] && m[10]==d[10] && m[11]==d[11] )
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4] && m[5]== d[5] && m[6]== d[6] && m[7]==d[7] && m[8]==d[8] && m[9]==d[9] && m[10]==d[10])
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4] && m[5]== d[5] && m[6]== d[6] && m[7]==d[7] && m[8]==d[8] && m[9]==d[9] )
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4] && m[5]== d[5] && m[6]== d[6] && m[7]==d[7] && m[8]==d[8])
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4] && m[5]== d[5] && m[6]== d[6] && m[7]==d[7])
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4] && m[5]== d[5] && m[6]== d[6] )
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4] && m[5]== d[5] )
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4])
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3]  )
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2]  )
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1])
            printf("%s ",d );
        else if( m[0]==d[0] )
            printf("%s ",d );
        else 
            printf(" No such word exists in file");
    }
   }
  }
}
```

When I type:

```
india
```

Output should be:

```
   india

   indian

   indians
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: Dude, don't copy paste code like that. Always DRY (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself). Use a loop with `strncmp` to shorten it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check functions:

`char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)` (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm)

or

`int strncmp(const char *str1, const char *str2, size_t n)`
(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncmp.htm)

which will help u with substring matching.

---

Your program may be altered as (not checked):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char m[50], d[50];
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("NOW.TXT","r");
    printf("Enter a word\n");
    scanf("%s", m);


    while( fgets (d, 50, fp)!=NULL ) 
    {    
        if (strstr(d, m) != NULL) {
            printf("%s ", d);
        }    

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could give an algorithm for this. What you can do is read the entire text from the text file and assign it to a single string.Then split the string you got from text file into words with space as delimeter and add these to an array.

Till this point you are with all words of that text file in a single array..!!

Now what you can do is for every string in the array check whether it contains the input given by user or not...If yes then print that string..

Hope this helps  :)

Answer (score 0):

So this bit of code makes absolutely no sense.

```
for(j=0; j<p; j++){
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    if( m[0]==d[0] && m[1]==d[1] && m[2]==d[2] && m[3]==d[3] && m[4]==d[4] && m[5]== d[5] && m[6]== d[6] && m[7]==d[7] && m[8]==d[8] && m[9]==d[9] && m[10]==d[10] && m[11]==d[11] && m[12]==d[12] && m[13]==d[13] && m[14]==d[14] && m[15]==d[15])
```

You're looping over all the characters in `m` for every character in `d` and then randomly comparing characters in both strings irrespective of the length of each string.

There are several ways you could do what you're trying to do, but in keeping with your current design you want something a bit like this:

```
for(j=0;j<p;j++) {
  for(i=0;(i+j<p) && (i<n) && (m[i]==d[i+j]);i++);
    if(i==n) {
      printf("%s ",d);
      break;
    }
}
```

This will loop over every character in `d` and look for the `n` characters that match between the 2 strings. After the second loop, `i` will contain how many characters match so if it's equal to `n` then you have a winner.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the post sometimes back on the same ground.. may be it is helpful for you..

http://clanguagestuff.blogspot.in/2015/06/comparing-username-stored-in-file-in-c.html

Answer (score 0):

No real answer more like general help.

This program has many problems concerning it's readability.

1. Don't use variable names which are unusable. Try to use names which explain themselfs like "numberOfLetters". don't force yourself to use short variables just because they are short. You can still use i,j,k for counting as they are widly execpted and known for that, but generally speaking: **Readability > Short**
2. If you have Problems which seem really repititive like this giant "else if" chances are you can use a loop. In this case some kind of loop which takes each iteration one less value.